# Парсер файлов настроек

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть одна проблемка, я попытался написать свой парсер для чтения таких файлов:

Есть string name, path, mod_path, tags[], picture, supported_version;

Я хочу спарсить такой файл:

```
name="Name"
path="C:/"
mod_path="F:/"
tags={
     "Electron"
     "Magma"
     "Logic"

}
picture="img.png"
supported_version="1.0.1"
```

В итоге парсер спарсит и внесет в string переменные `string name = "Name" ; string path = "C:/" ; string mod_path = "F:/" ; string tags[] = { Electron, Magma, Logic } ; string picture = "img.png" ; string supported_version = "1.0.1";`

P.S между `=` и `"` может быть пробелы и перед `=`. (т.е их не учитывать, а в " " - учитывать)

Но мои попытки найти понятный пример, не особо удались - ибо я находил сложные и математические, а для такого плана нет(или просто не нашел). Прошу помочь как реализовать или подкиньте простые для понимания(не математические) (Можно варианты на чистом С++ или Qt).

Спасибо.

Comment: При чем сдесь математика - вообще не понятно. Я бы слегка модифицировал синтаксис данного файла (добавил бы запятые в списке) и использовал бы lua в качестве парсера.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch увы мне надо сделать парсинг этого файла. А про математику - просто я находил примеры которые были для парсинга выражений математических. И я подумал что если моего плана файл, то выйдет еще сложнее. А хочется проще и не медленно по скорости.

Lua не вариант.

Comment: вы конечено интересный такой: хочется просто и быстро, но простой и быстрый вариант не подходит... Вы уж определитесь что вы хотите, потому что если вам нужно написать свой мини-язык (а это будет ни что иное), то не будет ни просто ни быстро (с вашими уровнем знаний). Вообщем смотрите regex

Comment: Вам нужен именно такой формат? Просто если минимально подкорректировать ваш файл - можно получить JSON. А в Qt есть инструменты для его разбора.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @maestro добавление еще одного уровня вложенности, изменение = на :, добавление ковычек, добавление запятых в каждой строке - у вас интересные представления о минимальности) сравните это с добавлением двух запятых в массиве tags для получения валидного lua кода